# How to implement a state that wait for other minions finishing certain jobs then execute certain state?

Tags: salt-stack

How to implement a state that wait for other minions finishing certain jobs then execute certain state?

For example, I have a cluster of minions called minion-aha1 to minion-aha3, and I install hadoop and hbase on these 3 minions. Now, I would like to convert them to HA mode. Suppose minion-aha1 is the leader. So the logic flow would be:

```
Start hadoop and hbase on all 3 minions
-> minion-aha1 wait till rest of minions are hadoop and hbase are on and healthy
-> minion-aha1 call join (e.g. stop namenode, hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits, start namenode)
-> rest minions call nn2 (e.g. hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby, start namenode)
```

I already knew how to convert hbase to HA mode, and I could set the leader in grain, just curious on how to shrink above procedure to single-line, i.e.

```
salt 'minion-aha*' state.apply hadoop.hbase_to_ha
```

Or even salt.orch state would be acceptable. The above would fail due to minion-aha1 never know the state of rest of minions. In other words, it might run successfully once if the developer is lucky, but I look for the solution would run successfully every time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I benefit from this answer with some modification:

[Trigger event on Master and wait for "response event" on Salt Minion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252768/trigger-event-on-master-and-wait-for-response-event-on-salt-minion)

For custom event sent to the salt master, e.g. mycompany/hbase/status/*/start, I have to send event -> saltutil.sync_all, then the wait_for_event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this without making use of an Orchestration SLS, you could look at one of the following approaches:

- use the [Salt Mine](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/) to publish information from a Minion to the Master, which can then be retrieved by another one
- use [Peer Communication](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/ref/peer.html) to allow one Minion to generate a job to be executed on another one